# Display liste of items grouped by catégorie

Tags: template-override, joomla-4

I create a blog liste modèle category in joomla 4,  need some help to customise it

In ordre to display item grouped by catégorie
Like

```
Cat 0 parent
  |_Cat1
     |_Item 1
     |_Item 2
  |_Cat2
     |_Item 1
     |_Item 2
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please share the research that you've done and the attempts that you have made.

Comment: hello i check override and children layout but i didn't find how ...
for now i can do this
item1
item2
cat1
cat2